# Ping for 4 times

Tags: command-line, ping

Usually I use ping to check my internet connection. In windows, if I use:

```
ping google.com
```

I get only 4 information ping, but on Ubuntu, if I use that command, the ping can' stop until I stop it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. Can I ping only for 4 times then stopped? If I can, can I use it as default?

Comment: Nearly every command (including ping) in Linux comes with extensive manuals: 1. Its help text: `ping --help` and 2. Its manual page: `man ping`

Answer (score 101, accepted):

As Olive Twist already answered, `ping -c 4 google.com` will do it.

If you want to make this as a default, one way is to create an alias for ping with:

`alias ping='ping -c 4'`

Save it to your `~/.bashrc` file to make it permanent or it will last only for the current terminal session.

Comment: +1 for the alias. I was thinking about a system wide settings. Yours is a nice solution

Answer (score 33):

Yes, you can. You need to use `-c` option to tell the ping to do this, like

```
ping -c 4 google.com
```

The `-c` option tells ping program to stop after sending (or receiving ) specified number of  `ECHO_RESPONSE` packets.

See the [ping manual page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man8/ping.8.html) for details.

Answer (score -2):

When you want to ping with IP, type:

```
ping -c 4 192.168.1.100
```

(remember to put a space between your number `-c 4` and the IP address!

Some will think:

```
 ping 192.168.1.100 -c 4 (WRONG)
```

Comment: `ping 192.168.1.100 -c 4` is NOT wrong.